# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.custom_timer'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I pulled code from another team member whose code base works without errors, but anytime I try to run this I get this error. I tried renaming the class and importing in different ways but nothing's been working. Here's the following main code.

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCharts import *

from database.db import MySql
from package.main_chart import StockChart
from package.indicator_charts import IndicatorCharts
from scripts.custom_timer import RepeatedTimer
```

here is the current file structure

Why is RepeatedTimer not being detected?

Comment: Where is `RepeatedTimer`?

Comment: It's in `custom_timer`.

Comment: If the `RepeatedTimer` is a file the, make sure that is is present in the `scripts` directory, if not, and the `RepeatedTimer` is a `class` or `function` then make sure that it is present in the `__init__.py` of the `scripts` folder.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, if it is in `custom_timer.py` then use

```py
from scripts.custom_timer import RepeatedTimer
```

#### You can have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules

Comment: I tried this and I'm now getting a different error.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.custom timer'

Comment: oh, did you use `scripts.custom timer` instead of `scripts.custom_timer`